# What's the correct way to work with WordPress posts from the API?

Tags: wordpress

What's the trick to working with WordPress posts as pure data structures?

Traditionally, you use "The Loop" and output data via functions like this:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

These functions dump text directly into the response.

Using $wpdb, I can get back an array of posts like this:

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SOME SQL HERE", OBJECT);
```

I then get a array of stdClass objects which are...Post-ish, I guess.  They have properties for "post_title" and such, but there's no Permalink, which makes me think this isn't the "correct" Post object to use.  Also, the "post_content" isn't complete HTML -- it still has line-breaks, etc.

When iterating this array, I've found I have to do this:

```
foreach ($events as $post)
{
   setup_postdata($post);
   ...
```

This puts that post in the global scope.  Then I can use the aforementioned functions to write content out, and use functions like this to get metadata:

```
$display_date = get_custom_field('display_date');
```

Is there a better way? This just seems...odd.  Is there a way to get a complete representation of a post as an object, with all metadata, and everything else I need to manipulate it from the data level, rather than just assuming I want to dump output to the response?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead, just like

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;
```

All you have to prepare the `$args` arguments array to make a customized query, for example, you can use

```
// Display posts that have "books" tag
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'tag=books' );
```

or

```
// Display posts that have these categories
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=event,news' );
```

or more complex one like

```
// Display posts tagged with bob, under people custom taxonomy
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'people' => 'bob'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can also use [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) but it's a bit different than [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and you can also use [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) and use a [custom select query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query) only when there is no way to get the desired result using WordPress' way. There is a nice answer about [WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts), read this for better understanding.

Comment: This is correct. wpdb can be used in some situations, but WP_Query is the bees knees for just about everything. It has all the things you need to use posts effectively. The loop is built on WP_Query essentially, but using it as Sheikh suggests will allow customization without the downside of WPDB.

Comment: The result of WP_Query is an array of WP_Post objects, which is a step in the right direction, but they still don't seem to have a permalink on them.  From that object, how do I get the URL to a post?  And what about the custom fields of a post -- those don't seem to be on the object either.

Comment: I found it: get_permalink($post-ID).  I still don't understand why this just can't be a property on the object.  Also, I found that virtual properties will give you the metadata -- just address them as if they exist: $post->my_custom_field_name.

Comment: Actually I don't know why `this just can't be a property on the object` but if you want to use a filter using meta fields then you can do it using [meta_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters), you can also use the global `$post` variable, it's a lot more about `WP_Query` to explain but not possible in this context, anyways, [read this](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/14/using-wp_query-wordpress/), hope it would be helpful.